# How can I install Keycloak as a service, so it starts automatically?

Tags: service, windows-services, wildfly, keycloak

I have installed WildFly 10.0 as a service, I ran the service.bat file, but I need Keycloak as service too. If I run Keycloak's *service.bat* file it says:

> ERROR: Service WildFly already exists.

My Keycloak version is 3.3.0, so basically the service of Keycloak wants to install WildFly as service, or I don't understand.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a solutions with the [NSSM - the Non-Sucking Service Manager](https://nssm.cc/download)

It's only 324 KB in size, really simple and efficient. Most importantly, it requires no installation and does not depend on components such as .NET. So it is easy to distribute/pack with your software and even if it is outdated, it works with all current Windows versions.

**install.bat**

```
nssm.exe install "Keycloak" "keycloak/run.bat"
nssm.exe set "Keycloak" AppDirectory "keycloak/"
nssm.exe set "Keycloak" Description "Keycloak Identity and Access Management"
```

I use a separated *run.bat*, if parameters change (as they have in the past keycloak releases) I can modify the *run.bat* instead of reinstalling the service.

**keycloak/run.bat**

```
bin/kc.bat --config-file "../conf/keycloak.conf" start --optimized
```

**conf/keycloak.conf**

```
http-port=6060
...
```

Answer (score 2):

**As of Keycloak 12 on Windows**

copy *[keycloak install dir]*\docs\contrib\scripts\service to [keycloak install dir]\bin

from *[keycloak install dir]*\bin\service Run

```
service.bat /name keycloak /display Keycloak /desc "Keycloak Http Server"
```

Answer (score 1):

The exact syntax of the service script depends on the operating system you're using. On Windows, you can include a name argument to change the name of the installed service:

```
.\service.bat install /name Keycloak
```

Answer (score 0):

Wildfly is the default name used to create the service. You can change the defaults in the `service.bat` file. Look for the following entries in the file and update as required before executing `service install`.

```
rem defaults
set SHORTNAME=Wildfly
rem NO quotes around the display name here !
set DISPLAYNAME=WildFly
rem NO quotes around the description here !
set DESCRIPTION=WildFly Application Server
```

Answer (score 0):

To install **Keycloak 10 as a Windows service**, I followed these steps (change paths as needed!):

1. Add these lines in C:\tools\keycloak-10.0.2\bin\standalone.bat

   set JAVA_HOME=C:\tools\openjdk-15_windows-x64\jdk-15
   set JBOSS_HOME=C:\tools\keycloak-10.0.2

(I don't like this so much, but I don't want this setting at system or account level)

2. Open a cmd as Administrator ([WINDOWS]+R, cmd, [CTRL][SHIFT][ENTER])

   cd C:\tools\keycloak-10.0.2

   md bin\service

   xcopy /s docs\contrib\scripts\service\ bin\service

   cd bin\service

   service.bat install /name keycloak /display Keycloak /startup

   net start keycloak

To uninstall, you can do

service.bat /uninstall /name keycloak

P.S. Run across
"**WFLYSRV0239: Aborting with exit code 1**"
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3712111

Solution: make sure JBOSS_HOME is accessible and read-write for the windows user running the service.